# Lazy Load sub files/folder in Directory Tree View

Tags: c#, .net, file, treeview

I am currently working on a File Browsing control (https://github.com/gregyjames/FileBrowser) but I am having performance issues with the code. Currently,as you can see [here](https://github.com/gregyjames/FileBrowser/blob/master/FileBrowser/FolderBrowser/FileBrowser.cs), I have two recursive loops that load all the files in the root directory into the tree view. How can I modify this to initially load the sub folders in the root directory, then load the sub directories of each directory upon user selection (i.e if a users selects a folder, then I loads the contents). Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the simplest/minimum amount of code I could think of to lazy load the child nodes

```
// Form1.OnLoad 
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    var root = new FolderFileNode(_path);
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
    root.LoadNodes();

    treeView1.BeforeSelect += (sender, args) =>
    {              
        //This flickers a lot , a bit less between BeginUpdate/EndUpdate
        (args.Node as FolderFileNode)?.LoadNodes();                
    };

    treeView1.AfterExpand += (sender, args) =>
    {                
        (args.Node as FolderFileNode)?.SetIcon();                
    };

    treeView1.AfterCollapse += (sender, args) =>
    {
        (args.Node as FolderFileNode)?.SetIcon();                
    };
}                    

class FolderFileNode : TreeNode
{
    private readonly string _path;

    private readonly bool _isFile;

    public FolderFileNode(string path)
    {            
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(path));
        Text = Path.GetFileName(path);
        _isFile = File.Exists(path);
        _path = path;

        if (!_isFile && Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(_path).Any())
        {
            //Will indicate there is children 
            Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
        }
        SetIcon();
    }

    public void SetIcon()
    {
        // image[2] is Folder Open image
        ImageIndex = _isFile ? ImageIndex = 1 :  IsExpanded ? 2 : 0;
        SelectedImageIndex = _isFile ? ImageIndex = 1 :  IsExpanded ? 2 : 0;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> _children;
    public void LoadNodes()
    {
        if (!_isFile && _children == null)
        {
           // _children = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(_path);
           // Or Add Directories first
           _children = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(_path).ToList();
            ((List<string>) _children).AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path)); 

            //Theres one added in the constructor to indicate it has children 
            Nodes.Clear();

            Nodes.AddRange(
                _children.Select(x => 
                    // co-variant
                    (TreeNode) new FolderFileNode(x))
                    .ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great thank you! Is there any way I can still so the +/- on the folders to indicate that there are sub-contents or group the files and the folders together? Currently it combines the files and folders together. How can I show the folders first than the files? Similar to window's sort by type.

Comment: edited with the features requested , ... don't you need to accept the answer ?
 :)

Comment: Oops, my bad! Thanks again!